# Ожидание события

Tags: c++, winapi

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании `Event` и функций `WaitForSingleObject` и `SetEvent`. Я создаю два потока: в одном я жду через `Mutex` что-то (неважно что), а в другом во время этого ожидания печатаю в консоль. И нужно, чтобы второй поток (печать в консоль) выполнялся, пока выполняется первый, т.е. когда первый завершится, второй тоже сразу должен завершиться. Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью вышеперечисленных функций.

Вот код функции `thread` для `hThreads[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, thread, (void *)i, 0, &id);`:

```
unsigned __stdcall thread(void *param)
{
    int id = (int)param;
    char c = '.';

    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
            //cout << "case 0";
            hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, nameForMutex);
            while (!hMutex)
                hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, nameForMutex);
            SetEvent(hEvents[0]);
            break;

        case 1:
            //cout << "case 1";
            while (!WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], INFINITE))
            {
                //cout << "while";
                cout << "Wait for Human";
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    cout << c;
                    Sleep(700);
                }
                cout << "\r";
                cout << "Wait for Human";
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << "\r";
                //WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[id], INFINITE);
            }
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Error in threads";
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. второй поток выполняется, пока первый поток не выполнит `SetEvent(hEvents[0]);`. Мне кажется, что проблема в условии `while`, как-то по-другому надо использовать проверку `WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], INFINITE)`.

Comment: А зачем вам `Mutex`? Вы с прицелом на взаимодействие между разными _процессами_? Внутри одного процесса вроде бы достаточно `CreateEvent`/`PulseEvent`. PS: А нет, event тоже бывает общим.

Comment: Подождите, а откуда вы взяли код `while (!WaitForSingleObject(...))`? Результат `WaitForSingleObject` надо сравнивать с `WAIT_OBJECT_0` и тому подобным.

Comment: Вместо `INFINITE` поставьте 0

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Официальный пример от Microsoft использует именно `INFINITE`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: По-моему, должно быть так `while (WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )`, т.е. чтобы WaitForSingleObject не замирала в ожидании, а сразу выходила, и ждем, пока она не вернет WAIT_OBJECT_0, равное нулю.

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем именно проблема. Навскидку могу сказать что не вижу CreateEvent и меня очень смущает преобразование указателя id = (int)param, правильное использование WaitForSingleObject выше описано.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Ой, слона-то я и не приметил! И правда: в коде `SetEvent`, но `CreateMutex`.

Comment: @VladD Ну наверно `hEvents[0]=CreateEvent()` он вызывает где-то в другом месте. А мьютекс ему нужен для другого.

Comment: Спасибо всем! `while (WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], 0) )` помогло.

1) Mutex мне для других целей.

2) Я пробовал `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, результат тот же, т.е. сравнивать можно и так, и так.

3) `CreateEvent` в `main` же, я просто функцию сюда скопировал.

4) С `id = (int)param` всё хорошо.

Comment: @zenden2k: Поскольку эта вся механика не работает, хотелось бы видеть весь релевантный код.

Comment: @compl: Сравнивать лучше так, как предписано. Потому что если на другой платформе значение `WAIT_OBJECT_0` будет случайно не 0, код работать не будет.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, должно быть так

```
while (WaitForSingleObject(hEvents[0], 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
```

т.е. чтобы функция `WaitForSingleObject` не замирала в ожидании, а сразу выходила, и ждем, пока она не вернет `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, равное нулю.